# SQLite with CursorAdapter to Custom ListView

Tags: android

How fill Custom `ListView` with Data from `SQLite database`?
Which type of Adapter I should use?

screenshot http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/assets/list_view/Custom_Base_adapter-6c6a43148474a723639fcbb8c85f5786.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do `ListView` with Data from SQLite try use `CursorAdapter`.

## ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

// The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
// you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
}
// The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TitleLabel);
    TextView txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SecondLabel);
    TextView txt3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ThirdLabel);
    // Extract properties from cursor
    // getString(int) - number of column
    String value1 = cursor.getString(1);
    String value2 = cursor.getString(2);
    String value3 = cursor.getString(3);
    String value4 = cursor.getString(4);


    txt1.setText(value1);
    txt2.setText("value2: " + value2);
    txt3.setText("value3: " + value3 + "value4: " + value4);

    }
}
```

## MainActivity.java

helper - Database helper class

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    final Cursor ListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename", null);
    final ListAdapter todoAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, ListCursor, 0);
  // Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
    listview.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display single field in listview then use simple Arrayadapter i.e.

```
DBHelper mydb = new DBHelper(this);
  ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllCotacts();
  ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

  ListView obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

other wise implement custom adapter extends with BaseAdapter.